# Denial of service:regular expression : fortify pointed out a issue

Tags: java, security, fortify

Hi  i am getting denial of service:regular expressioon warning on  the below line

**billingApplicationAcctId = billingApplicationAcctId.replaceAll("\" + s, "");**

you can see below code for further reference

```
   if (null != formatBillingAcctIdInd && formatBillingAcctIdInd.equals("Y")
                    && billingApplicationCode.equalsIgnoreCase(EPWFReferenceDataConstants.BILLING_APPICATION_ID.KENAN.name())) {
                Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
                Matcher match = pt.matcher(payment.getBillingApplicationAccntId());
                while (match.find()) {
                    String s = match.group();
                    billingApplicationAcctId = billingApplicationAcctId.replaceAll("\\" + s, "");
                }
            }
```

what should i do instead of above code , so i will not get fortify DOS warning

Comment: "Get anything not `a-zA-Z0-9` and remove it - prefixed by '\' from the actual id"? Is this even correct? - If so, just cut any characters from `a-zA-Z0-9` by building `billingApplicationAcctId` by a string buffer and copying character by character that lies outside this range. Do it with a simple loop, and go character by character and check, whether the char value is in an excluded range...

Comment: @TreffnonX i am not clearly getting you can you please elaborate it by giving an example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go away from your regex code, you can compare the input character-wise. Just replace

```java
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher match = pt.matcher(payment.getBillingApplicationAccntId());
while (match.find()) {
    String s = match.group();
    billingApplicationAcctId = billingApplicationAcctId.replaceAll("\\" + s, "");
}
```

with:

```java
String rawInput = payment.getBillingApplicationAccntId();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : rawInput.toCharArray()) {
    // any char that is an english letter or 0-9 is included. The rest is thrown away...
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
billingApplicationAcctId = sb.toString();
```